# How to remove slug from hierarchical custom types in 3.5.2

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

I know that is not suggested and that there is lots of discussion about this argument out there. Unfortunally, after a week of trying and tests, I have not managed to remove the slug from my custom type yet. Here's the situation:

### The url structure I need

- post **/blog/my-blog-post** [ok!]
- pages **/parent-service/service** [ok!]
- portfolio **/portfolio/my-first-work** [ok!]
- static **/parent-static-page/static-page** [<<<--- here is the problem]

### My configuration

- Wordpress 3.5.2
- Custom type 'static': hierarchical; without any 'rewrite' rule.
- Custom type 'portfolio': not hierarchical; 'rewrite' => array( 'with_front'=> false )
- Permalink structure: /blog/%postname%/
- As front page I set the static page 'blog'

### The problem

- post **blog/my-blog-post** [ok!]
- pages **/websites/dynamic-websites** [ok!]
- portfolio **/portfolio/my-first-work** [ok!]
- static **/who-i-am/terms** [<<<--- here is the problem]

### What I've tryed

#### Nothing

At the beginning, as expected, the url of the 'static' post "My test page" is **/blog/static/my-test-page**

#### 'rewrite' => array( 'slug'=>'', 'with_front'=>false )

I've removed the front from the url...good! Now I've **/static/my-test-page**

#### 'rewrite' => array( 'slug'=>false, 'with_front'=>false )

It doesn't remove the slug. I have **/static/my-test-page** yet.

#### 'rewrite' => array( 'slug'=>'/', 'with_front'=>false )

It removes the slug! Now I have **/my-test-page**. Unfortunally **all the pages return me a 404 error**.

#### 'Remove slug from custom post type' plugin

Even though it works only if my permalink structure is /%postname%, I've tried to install this plugin and change my permalink structure to do a test. It works, but unfortunally **doesn't respect the hierarchical nature** of my 'static' type.

#### [The tutorial by Joakin Lim](http://www.ultimatewebtips.com/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type/)

It doesn't work. In particular, after adding `function book_rewrite_rule()` it says that my custom type now will be accessible from **/my-test-page** as well as **/static/my-test-page**, but it doesn't work for me. I can access only from **/static/my-test-page**. I've tryed also to apply all the tutorial, also doing some changements and tests, but without success

#### [The tutorial from vip.wordpress](http://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/remove-the-slug-from-your-custom-post-type-permalinks/)

If I change 'event' with 'static' in both functions, I can access my page from **blog/parent-page/my-test-page**. If I add 'rewrite' => ( 'with_front'=>false ) everything brokes and I can access only from **static/parent-page/my-test-page**

#### Other solutions and tests

Unfortunally, with my actual reputation, I can't link more than two links. But I've tryed also the solution found in ryansechrest.com, shibashake.com and - of course - ALL the questions posted in this portal before. Off course every time I've flushed all the permalinks rules, visiting the setting page, saving the options, changing them twice and save them again, using the `global $wp_rewrite; $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();`. I've tryed lots of combination with the 'rewrite' array and the different solutions above.

Have you any suggestion?

Comment: Reviving a question that was asked soooo long ago (great question BTW). Did you ever find a solution? Could a solution be to use the default WP page types and use a custom page template?

Comment: Hi @guiniveretoo, I still not have found a solution. In my website I'm implementing an experiment: I will convert all my custom post types (portfolio, tools, info) and all posts in pages. In that manner I'll simplify structure and URLs. Then I'll specify pages with meta fields; also the front end will result simpler.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this I always disable the slug when adding the custom post type, and add custom rewrites with the `add_rewrite_rule` function.

See also this codex page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule